# Config Teamcity 8 and gitLab 6.0.2

Tags: configuration, continuous-integration, teamcity, gitlab

Hello i am trying to config teamcity to work with gitlab but i get an error : "Test connection failed in myProject ...service=git-upload-pack" 
Someone know what is the problem?
Or maybe have sometips or toturial for this?

Thanks. Din.

Comment: Could you upgrade GitLab to see if the issue persists then?

Comment: Any luck with this @Din Grinshtein?

Comment: @VonC, do you have any experience with this?, how about integrating TeamCity and Merge Request on Gitlab?

Comment: @CarlosCastellanos No, I haven't tested that particular setup.

Comment: @VonC what combo (Gitlab + ????) do you have experience with?

Comment: No combo for now. In the next future, I will study the integration of GitLab with Jenkins.